# pass values of inputs form to then{} section in sweetalert2?

Tags: javascript, sweetalert2

I have a block of code:

```
<form class="myfrom">
<select name="name1"><option>..<option></select>
<select name="name2"><option>..<option></select>
<select name="name3"><option>..<option></select>
</form>
```

I copied top block html code to sweetalert via jquery. (So Now,I have 2 same block in the Document)...I did it with this code:

```
var form = $('.myfrom').html();
swal({
    title: 'edit form',
    html: form,
    showCancelButton: true
}).then((result) => {
  if (result.value) {
     swal({
     title: 'done',
     text: 'it has been done!',
     type: 'success',
   });
   $.ajax({
      //call ajax
   });
 }
```

How can I pass value of selectboxes element to `then{}` section?

Answer (score 0):

Hi have you tried giving your select inputs id's?

Also if you are to do this you would need to have you html created inside the swal({ .. }) code as jQuery will take the first element with the specified id.

So you code would now look like this

**HTML**

```
<head><!--Incase you don't have jquery loaded-->
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<!--Not needed anymore-->
<!--<form class="myfrom">
<select name="name1"><option>..<option></select>
<select name="name2"><option>..<option></select>
<select name="name3"><option>..<option></select>
</form>-->
```

**javascript**

```
swal({
    title: 'edit form',
    html:'<form class="myfrom">'+
    '<select name="name1" id="name1">'+
        '<option> .1.</option>' +
        '<option> .2.</option>' +
        '<option> .3.</option>' +
    '</select>'+
    '<select name="name2" id="name2">'+
        '<option> .1.</option>' +
        '<option> .2.</option>' +
        '<option> .3.</option>' +
     '</select>'+
     '<select name="name3" id="name3" > '+
        '<option> .1.</option>'+
        '<option> .2.</option>'+
        '<option> .3.</option>'+
    '</select>'+
    '</form>',
    showCancelButton: true
}).then((result) => {
    var name1 = $('#name1').val();//The value of select input name1
    var name2 = $('#name2').val();//The value of select input name2
    var name3 = $('#name3').val();//The value of select input name3

    console.log(name3 + " " + name2 + " " + name3);

    if (result.value) {
        swal({
            title: 'done',
            text: 'it has been done!',
            type: 'success',
        });
        $.ajax({
            //call ajax
        });
    }
});
```

I hope this helps Good luck.